# OpenMP test lock without setting it

Tags: c, openmp

According to [OpenMP specification](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu159.html), `omp_test_lock` sets a lock if it is available and returns false otherwise. I'm looking for a routine which would allow to test a lock without setting it. How can I do that in OpenMP?

Comment: Release the lock if it was successfully set?

Comment: @Gerhard the only way I could come up with, possible redundant overhead?

Comment: There is no such function in OpenMP. Why do you need it? By the time this function returns you do not know anything about the state of the lock (other thread may changed it already). I think its use would either cause a data race or it is better to implement your task without locks.